# Two inline divs (pc), with vertical-center align on media

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to design a topbar for a page (2 inline divs) and I'm having trouble with centering them vertically on media screens.

[(Paint) example what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVEE0.png)

I am using `float: left;` to make **div**s inline + `display: inline-block` for **li** elements and it works great, but it keeps them inline on media screens.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: please create code snippet. thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you currently have, code included? We're not able to help with the information you've provided

Answer (score -1):

Is this something that could be resolved with media queries (these allow you to alter the css state of an element, based on screen size):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
.your-class-here {
display: block;
}
}
```

remember to add the relevant meta tag to your html head element too:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Cheers

Marky

Answer (score -1):

Vertical centering in CSS is notoriously difficult - I would recommend using Flexbox to solve this kind of thing - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/